# How to add style on whose input attribute "name" is only know?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can we add style on label which is front of text field . I know only name attr  of textfield .I use dform plugin which convert json to forum .
I need to add style using name of text field (name "timeout")

here is mark up

```
<label class="ui-dform-label">Timeout</label>
<input type="text" name="timeout" class="ui-dform-text">
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can [traverse the DOM](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/):

```
$('input[name=timeout]').prev('label').css(...);
```

You can't do this in CSS alone since there is no [previous sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Comment: can we add using css .not using js

Comment: Actually css is more powerful than js

Comment: No. Why did you tag your question with jQuery if you want a CSS solution? *"Actually css is more powerful than js"* I really doubt that, since JS is a programming language, and CSS is not.